# Communication from parent state to child state in UI-router for AngularJS (with components)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to get some data of a component in a parent state into the component of its children state.

I know that if these data are in the `resolve` of my parent state I can access them through the bindings of the component in the children state, but this isn't my case.

How can I realize it? (possibly without using a factory)

**Example**

*module.js*

```
...
$stateProviver.state({
    name: 'admin',
    component: 'aComp',
    url: '/admin'

}).state({
    name: 'admin.child',
    component: 'bComp',
    url: '/child'
});
```

*aComp.js*

```
...
this.data = {
    person: {
       age: 15,
       name: 'admin',
       ...
    }
}
function goToBComp() {
    $state.go('.child');
}
```

*aComp.html*

```
<div>I'm a component, I don't have bComp inside me</div>
```

*bComp.js*

```
...
// In this component I need to access the 'data' object defined in aComp.js
```

Comment: Is the router directly routing to the child component (is the child component inside a `ui-view` of a parent state?)

Comment: No, the child component isn't inside a `ui-view` of a parent state @FrankModica

Comment: So can you just pass the data down from parent to child, like one normally would? I think some more details of your setup or a live example would help.

Comment: the child state has a component that isn't child of its parent state component. So I don't realize how can I pass down the data @FrankModica

Comment: I'have added some details in my question @FrankModica

Comment: Hmm, since the parent and child are really not connected (I’m curious - why are they parent and child states then?) then you might need the parent to pass data to a service which is accessed by the child.

Comment: They are not connected because I don't have to show the child component when the parent state is active, but the two states are related. I thought that using this state hierarchy I could exploit the data sharing between them, without using a service. @FrankModica

Comment: Ok - regarding resolves, does the parent resolve simply not run when the child is loading? Or is it that you don’t use a resolve to load data into the parent?

Comment: I don't use a resolve to load data into the parent @FrankModica

Comment: I don't know if it's the right way to do that, but I reach the goal using `params` object in state definition, passing the data through it and accessing them with `$transition$` object in the child. (this.$transition$.params('to').myData)